# "invalid regular expression: parentheses () not balanced"

Tags: regex, postgresql

I'm getting the error `invalid regular expression: parentheses () not balanced` while executing a query. The error refers to this part:

```
substring(every_x1, '\m[0-9]*\.?[0-9]'),
substring(every_x2, '\m[0-9]*\(?|-|to|TO)'),
substring(every_x2, '\m[0-9]*\(?|time|TIME)')
```

I checked it in an online parentheses checker, and it's supposed to be okay. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `\(` escapes the `(` so it's not treated as an "open parentheses" but as a literal character. And therefor the `)` is unbalanced

Comment: Well, depends on what you want to achieve. If you want to define a regex group, then don't escape the opening parentheses. If you want to search for an opening and closing parentheses, escape the closing parentheses

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what is the exact pattern you are looking but if you were looking to find the actual "(" (parentheses) sign maybe you should escape it the second time also, somethin like in this example:

```
select substring(every_x2, '\m[0-9]*\(?|-|to|TO\)')::float as part_1
```

Comment: I wasn't. I tried to extract phrases like '4-6' and '4 to 6' feilds

Answer (score 0):

Try this regular expression `'\m(\d+(?:\s*-\s*|\s*to\s*)\d+)\M')`.

```sql
select substring('123 12-56 xyz' from '\m(\d+(?:\s*-\s*|\s*to\s*)\d+)\M');
-- 12-56 
select substring('123 12 to 56 xyz' from '\m(\d+(?:\s*-\s*|\s*to\s*)\d+)\M');
-- 12 to 56
```